# Regex Optional Groups Captures with Values

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, inline, option-type, regex-lookarounds

I'm having difficulties extracting irregular data using Regex. I attempted to use Lookheads however when the value doesn't exist the entire match returns false. The data set is consistent all the way until I reach the characters starting with RXX. The RXX are unique identifiers (groups) and the numeric values in between each set of Rxx's is what I would like to capture and assigned them to group names.

The Rxx values are random from R01 to R15 and 1 to all 15 could exist in the string.

The string values could vary from

```
12*000000000**S304JB01811*8*0*8*4*4*34R0332R152~~~
12*000000000**S304JB01811*9*0*4*3*4*224R023R032R10234R1325~~~
```

I'm able to extract the values and assign a group name until I reach the Rxx
My attempt are extracting the values are as follow

```
S304JB0...(?<Total1>[\d]+).(?<Total2>[\d]+).(?<Total3>[\d]+).(?<Total4>[\d]+).(?<Total5>[\d]+).(?<Total6>[\d]+).(?<Total7>[\d]+)
```

Which gives me what I want below

```
Total1  `1`
Total2  `8`
Total3  `0`
Total4  `8`
Total5  `4`
Total6  `4`
Total7  `34`
```

Capturing the R03 value and assigning it to Row is achieved below but if the value R03 doesn't exist in the string then the entire match returns false

```
(?<Row3>(R03)[\d]+)
```

Looking how I can make these regex statements optional allowing me to return the following

```
Total1  `1`
Total2  `8`
Total3  `0`
Total4  `8`
Total5  `4`
Total6  `4`
Total7  `34`
Row1    `32`
Row15   `2`

S304JB0...(?<Total1>[\d]+).(?<Total2>[\d]+).(?<Total3>[\d]+).(?<Total4>[\d]+).(?<Total5>[\d]+).(?<Total6>[\d]+).(?<Total7>[\d]+)(?<Row3>(R03)[\d]+)(?<Row4>(R04)[\d]+) ------>  (?<Row15>(R15)[\d]+)
```

Thanks for your help

-Edited
Thanks for the quick reply Jorge

The input data will be
    12*000000000**S304JB01811*8*0*8*4*4*34R0332R152~~~

The output will be 9 captured groups results

```
 Group | Result

 Total1 = 1
 Total2 = 8
 Total3 = 0
 Total4 = 8
 Total5 = 4
 Total6 = 4
 Total7 = 34
 Row1   = 32
 Row15  = 2
```

My example is shared below with input and
https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/68

Hopefully this helped to clarify things
D.

Comment: Please add on your question what you have as data and the expected result from that data you provide. Right now the returned sequence does not exist on provided lines. Its difficult to us help you if we miss interpret the results.

Comment: I don't understand. Why is "`R03`" expected as a capture in `Row1`? Why not `Row3`?

Comment: sorry for the confusion.. And you are correct I wanted to assign R03 to Row3 not Row1  I've updated the question... Newbie..I'll try to be more careful next time.. Thanks

Comment: *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.* -- [Jamie Zawinski](https://www.jwz.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain this would be easier parsing char by char and storing each value.

As for the regex question, basically what you want to do is create all the groups, just like you've already tried, but you also want to make them optional, because not all groups might be there.

You can make the group optional with a construct like:

```
(?:R01(?<Row1>\d+))?
```

So you should add one of each to get the values in different capture groups. Notice I used the construct `(?:non-capturing)` which is exactly the same as a group, but it doesn't create a backreference. You can read about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

**Edit:** One more thing. You're using a `.` to allow any delimiter. However, performance-wise it would be better to use something like `\D` (anything except digits). In case of failure, it saves the regex engine quite a few backtracking steps.

This would be the whole expression, assuming the `Rxx` groups are always ordered.

```
S304JB0...(?<Total1>\d+)\D(?<Total2>\d+)\D(?<Total3>\d+)\D(?<Total4>\d+)\D(?<Total5>\d+)\D(?<Total6>\d+)\D(?<Total7>\d+)(?:R01(?<Row1>\d+))?(?:R02(?<Row2>\d+))?(?:R03(?<Row3>\d+))?(?:R04(?<Row4>\d+))?(?:R05(?<Row5>\d+))?(?:R06(?<Row6>\d+))?(?:R07(?<Row7>\d+))?(?:R08(?<Row8>\d+))?(?:R09(?<Row9>\d+))?(?:R10(?<Row10>\d+))?(?:R11(?<Row11>\d+))?(?:R12(?<Row12>\d+))?(?:R13(?<Row13>\d+))?(?:R14(?<Row14>\d+))?(?:R15(?<Row15>\d+))?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wG3aM3/69)

Comment: Allow me to say, I'd never use a regex like that. The answer was intended to show a way to solve the problem you described, as a way to explain regex syntax. Nonetheless, do find a different approach.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation. I'm using a application called Splunk which uses inline field extractions via Regex - . This answer is exactly want I needed.  Thank you